# After clear focus of edit text my other view got invisible in LG Optimus device

Tags: android, devise, android-edittext

On the click of reset button, I am resting all edit text and clearing the focus But this is working fine with other devices accept LG Optimus.
In LG Optimus after press reset button and clearing the focus of current view, other view got invisible.I don't know why LG Optimus is behaving like that because same code is working fine in other devices.
Before resting

[image]

after resting the edit text and clear focus.

[image]

```
   OnClickListener reset_ClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            getCurrentFocus().clearFocus();
            resetAllViews();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
};
```

And my resetALLViews() function is

```
    private void resetAllViews() {
    editTxtPiston.setText("");
    greyedOutTextField(editTxtPiston, false);
    editTxtRod.setText("");
    greyedOutTextField(editTxtRod, false);
    editTxtStroke.setText("");
    greyedOutTextField(editTxtStroke, false);
    editTxtPressure.setText("");
    greyedOutTextField(editTxtPressure, false);
    editTxtOilflow.setText("");
    greyedOutTextField(editTxtOilflow, false);
    editTxtAreaBore.setText("");
    editTxtAreaRod.setText("");
    editTxtVolumeBore.setText("");
    editTxtVolumeRod.setText("");
    editTxtForcrBore.setText("");
    greyedOutTextField(editTxtForcrBore, false);
    editTxtForceRod.setText("");
    greyedOutTextField(editTxtForceRod, false);
    editTxtTimeBore.setText("");
    greyedOutTextField(editTxtTimeBore, false);
    editTxtTimeRod.setText("");
    greyedOutTextField(editTxtTimeRod, false);
    editTxtVelocityBore.setText("");
    greyedOutTextField(editTxtVelocityBore, false);
    editTxtVelocityRod.setText("");
    greyedOutTextField(editTxtVelocityRod, false);
    editTxtOutflowBore.setText("");
    editTxtOutflowRod.setText("");
    editTxtRatio.setText("");
    settingsAllSpinnerToDefault();
    copy.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_disable);
    reset.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_disable);
    email.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_disable);
    copy.setEnabled(false);
    reset.setEnabled(false);
    email.setEnabled(false);
}
    // greyed out edit text field
private void greyedOutTextField(final EditText edit, boolean greyedOutState) {
    if (greyedOutState) {
        edit.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_darker_txt);
        edit.setClickable(false);
        edit.setCursorVisible(false);
        edit.setFocusable(false);
        edit.setEnabled(false);
        edit.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
        edit.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
        edit.setKeyListener(null);
    } else {
        edit.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_text);
        edit.setClickable(true);
        edit.setCursorVisible(true);
        edit.setFocusable(true);
        edit.setEnabled(true);
        edit.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        edit.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
    }
}
```

check this is my xml file

```
     <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/buttonView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#f9f9f9" >
      <!--On more Table layout is here and in this layout having edit text and  spinner-->
        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tableLayout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/side_header"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:padding="4dp" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
                style="@style/tablerow"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="65dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="2dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/area" />

                <TextView
                    style="@style/txt_for_backw"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/area" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/txt_bore_area"
                    style="@style/edit_for_gredout"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".3"
                    android:textSize="14sp" >
                </EditText>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/txt_rod_area"
                    style="@style/edit_for_gredout"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".3"
                    android:textSize="14sp">
                </EditText>

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spin_area"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".15"
                    android:entries="@array/array_metric_area" />
            </TableRow>

            <View
                style="@style/divider"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp" />

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow7"
                style="@style/tablerow"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="65dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="2dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/volume" />

                <TextView
                    style="@style/txt_for_backw"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/volume" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/txt_bore_volume"
                    style="@style/edit_for_gredout"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".3"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/txt_rod_volume"
                    style="@style/edit_for_gredout"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".3"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spin_volume"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".15"
                    android:entries="@array/array_metric_volume" />
            </TableRow>

            <View
                style="@style/divider"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp" />

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow8"
                style="@style/tablerow"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="65dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="2dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/force" />

                <TextView
                    style="@style/txt_for_backw"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/force" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/txt_bore_force"
                    style="@style/edit_side"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".3"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/txt_rod_force"
                    style="@style/edit_side"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".3"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spin_force"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".15"
                    android:entries="@array/array_metric_force" />
            </TableRow>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/row8"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="#f9f9f9"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img81"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/force_bore_side"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img82"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/force_rod_side"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/swip_row8"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:src="@drawable/swipe_uparrow"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                style="@style/divider"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp" />

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow9"
                style="@style/tablerow"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="65dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="2dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/time" />

                <TextView
                    style="@style/txt_for_backw"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/time" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/txt_bore_time"
                    style="@style/edit_side"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".3"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/txt_rod_time"
                    style="@style/edit_side"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".3"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spin_time"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".15"
                    android:entries="@array/array_metric_time" />
            </TableRow>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/row9"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="#f9f9f9"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img91"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/time_bore_side"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img92"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/time_rod_side"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/swip_row9"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:src="@drawable/swipe_uparrow"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                style="@style/divider"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp" />

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow10"
                style="@style/tablerow"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="65dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="2dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/velocity" />

                <TextView
                    style="@style/txt_for_backw"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/velovity" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/txt_bore_velocity"
                    style="@style/edit_side"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".3"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/txt_rod_velocity"
                    style="@style/edit_side"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".3"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spin_velocity"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".15"
                    android:entries="@array/array_metric_velocity" />
            </TableRow>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/row10"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="#f9f9f9"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img101"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/velocity_bore_side"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img102"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/velocity_rod_side"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/swip_row10"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:src="@drawable/swipe_uparrow"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                style="@style/divider"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp" />

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow11"
                style="@style/tablerow"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="65dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="2dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/outflow" />

                <TextView
                    style="@style/txt_for_backw"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/outflow" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/txt_bore_outflow"
                    style="@style/edit_for_gredout"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".3"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/txt_rod_outflow"
                    style="@style/edit_for_gredout"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".3"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spin_out_flow"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".15"
                    android:entries="@array/array_metric_outflow" />
            </TableRow>

            <View
                style="@style/divider"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp" />

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow12"
                style="@style/tablerow"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="65dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="2dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ratio" />

                <TextView
                    style="@style/txt_for_backw"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/ratio" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/txt_ratio"
                    style="@style/edit_for_gredout"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".3"
                    android:textSize="14sp"/>

                <EditText
                    style="@style/edit_side"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".3"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />

                <Spinner
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".15"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: please put some code.. just specify api levels. of different devices where there is behavior diiference

Comment: Lg-optimous android 4.0.4 having problem but the other devices like motrola(android 2.2),nexus(android 4.4),htc(android 4.0.3),samsung s3(4.1.2),xperia(4.1.2) working fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
    try {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       // getCurrentFocus().clearFocus(); instead of this get the one level up parent and clear its focus.
        resetAllViews();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: why i am getting current focus and clearing it bcz some of my edit text having focused when users intract with application.and when user click on reset i have to remove those edit text focus.

Comment: then get any one edittext reference and get its parent view.. then try to clear its focus.. better u post complete code so  can tell where set clear focus

Comment: I did but same problem occurring again.